# how to load all supporting jar in classpath in build.xml of apache ant

Tags: ant, build, hudson

I have make build.xml file for each projects which create jar,war,ear files

to call this build.xml i have make one more master build.xml

Now I have configure this project in Hudson

The problem is while building project from hudson , hudson can't convert relative path to absolute path.

So I want to do some global declaration and add all jar path and load all jar path in build.xml 's classpath

```
<fileset dir="${class.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>

<fileset dir="${AllJar.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to define individual filesets with some id and define your [master path with refid](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

Quote from the link:

> A path-like structure can include a reference to another path-like
>   structure (a path being itself a resource collection) via nested
>    elements:

```
<path id="base.path">
  <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
  <pathelement location="classes"/>
</path>

<path id="tests.path" cache="true">
  <path refid="base.path"/>
  <pathelement location="testclasses"/>
</path>
```

In this test.path includes base.path which in turn include ${classpath} and all jars from lib folder.